# Keycloak API always returns 401 with docker compose

Tags: spring-boot, docker, docker-compose, microservices, keycloak

I'm encountering an issue when trying to send a request to a service that requires an authentication token in the header, using Keycloak. Strangely, it returns a "401 Unauthorized" error when running in Docker Compose. However, when I send a normal request, it works perfectly fine.here is a screenshot

for both of controllers[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vK8iI.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ihRbo.png)

as you can see hello requires an authentification token using KeycloakAuthenticationToken
besides same controller works fine when i run my microservice and keycloak locally
here is a screenshot of my docker compose file

[[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZRLP5.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yrPcY.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yYS2R.png)

and how i configured my microservice to adapt keycloak

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MAwQo.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rS9MS.png)

just to clearify any controller without keyckloakauthentificationtoken works fine even with docker compose

I'd appreciate any insights or suggestions on why this issue might be occurring in docker compose

Comment: Can you check the response headers for any additional info? Logs for info? Check the token generated to see whether your configs are correct? Not much to go on from the info you have provided.